# How do I create a python environment for distribution with my app?

Tags: python, ruby, software-distribution

My Ruby application uses some Python scripts for specific calculations. At the moment I use the local Anaconda installation, but this is not convenient for distribution as it requires the user to install Anaconda. I would have the same issue if I used the system Python installation.

Is it possible to create a 'local' python environment that I can distribute and use with my app? I am working on Mac but the solution should work on PC as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Terminal I use `pip install virtualenv` to setup a virtual local environment for python. I believe the command is the same for Mac.

Reference: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Installshield to prepare installation for Mac, Windows and Linux.